# recognize swipe gesture on UITableviews inside a UIScrollView with paging enabled

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

Edit: I've begun implementing since I had first asked the question, so I'll rephrase the question with updated.

I've set up a UIScrollView with a UIPageControl and a series of UITableviews as subviews.  It works except for one problem: the subviews are each tableviews with horizontal swipe gestures on the table (the purpose of this swipe is to slide a cell and reveal a menu underneath the cell).  They don't work unless I disable scrolling on the UIScrollView.  But I still need a user to be able to swipe the scroll view outside when swiping outside the table.

Any guidance on how I can achieve this effect (swipe inside the table picked up by the table, swipe outside the table picked up by the scroll view).

Original:
I'd like to set up a series of UITableviews horizontally in a UIScrollView with paging enabled.  The tableviews will use a horizontal swipe gesture recognizer  (to slide the cell to the side and reveal a submenu).  And ideally horizontal swiping on the scroll view outside of a table (e.g. on the top of the scroll view) will cause UIScrollView to page to the next table.

Will the two swipe gestures work the way I hope? Or will the UIScrollView interfere?  If so how would you correct it?

Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm going with so far:

1. ScrollView scrolling remains disabled.
2. When handling swipe gesture on tableView, added this test: if locating the cell that the swipe was over returns nil, then invoke a scroll of the UIScrollView to the next page, and update currentPage of the PageControl object.

This works well enough, thought this way I'm missing the very real-time scrolling of having the UIScrollView sense swipe touches (in another words, if I swipe just a little bit and stop, the view still pages).

Still would love to hear a better solution from the SO community.

Regards